# Python Fabric Parallel Execution Failure on EC2: Updated

Tags: python, ssh, amazon-ec2, boto, fabric

So, background first. I was running Ubuntu 14.04 and running the following script without issue, where I `put` file on an EC2 instances. **Note**: I used the same IP's to illustrate both the success and failure, but pretend I had run this script from the start both times, generating new IP's everytime.

```
import boto.ec2
import os
from fabric.api import run, parallel, env, sudo
from fabric.tasks import execute
from fabric.operations import put

# file path python scripts and data
rps_file = "review_page_scraper.py"


# make sure hosts are clear before we add to them
env.hosts = []


# how many instances to start and how to split up the data frame 
num_instances = 3


# EC2 access keys
access_key = 'my_access_key'
secret_key = 'my_secret_key'


# get a connection to the east region
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1", 
                                  aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                                  aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)


# create the reservation of instances
reservation = conn.run_instances('my_ami_id',
                                 key_name='original_key', # my original key
                                 security_groups=['my_sec_grp'],
                                 instance_type='t2.micro',
                                 min_count=num_instances,
                                 max_count=num_instances)


# get list of instances
instance_lst = reservation.instances


# get a status update and wait if the instance isn't up and running yet
for instance in instance_lst:
    while instance.state != "running":
        sleep(5)
        instance.update()
    print "%s is running" % instance.ip_address


# get username and host, add 'ubuntu' as username
hosts = ["ubuntu@" + ip.ip_address for ip in instance_lst]
env.hosts = hosts # set environment variable


@parallel
def upload_scripts_data(file_name):
    path = "~/amazon_proj/amazon/"
    put(path + file_name, "~") # put it in the home dir of EC2 instance


# execute functions w/ rps_file
execute(upload_scripts_data, rps_file) # send review_page_scraper helpers
```

Here's the output:

```
In [25]: execute(upload_scripts_data, rps_file) # send    review_page_scraper helpers
[ubuntu@52.90.34.75] Executing task 'upload_scripts_data'
[ubuntu@54.173.57.59] Executing task 'upload_scripts_data'
[ubuntu@54.165.186.168] Executing task 'upload_scripts_data'
[ubuntu@52.90.34.75] put: /home/rerwin21/amazon_proj/amazon/review_page_scraper.py -> /home/ubuntu/review_page_scraper.py
[ubuntu@54.165.186.168] put: /home/rerwin21/amazon_proj/amazon/review_page_scraper.py -> /home/ubuntu/review_page_scraper.py
[ubuntu@54.173.57.59] put: /home/rerwin21/amazon_proj/amazon/review_page_scraper.py -> /home/ubuntu/review_page_scraper.py
Out[25]: 
{u'ubuntu@52.90.34.75': None,
 u'ubuntu@54.165.186.168': None,
 u'ubuntu@54.173.57.59': None}
```

**Now, the Problem:**
I ruined my Ubuntu install and lost my key-pair, generated using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, which I called 'original_key' when I imported the public key to AWS. So, I had to re-install Ubuntu and I chose 16.04. I generated a new key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and saved it to `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, for the private and public keys respectively.

I then imported the public key and saved it with the "id_rsa_pub" name. So, now I run the same script above, changing the `key_name` argument to "id_rsa_pub". Also, I ran `chmod 0400 id_rsa` per AWS's directions. The ouptut is:

```
In [22]: execute(upload_scripts_data, rps_file) 
[ubuntu@52.90.34.75] Executing task 'upload_scripts_data'
[ubuntu@54.173.57.59] Executing task 'upload_scripts_data'
[ubuntu@54.165.186.168] Executing task 'upload_scripts_data'
!!! Parallel execution exception under host u'ubuntu@54.165.186.168':
Process ubuntu@54.165.186.168:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
self.run()
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 242, in inner
submit(task.run(*args, **kwargs))
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 174, in run
return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/decorators.py", line 181, in inner
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-22-ed18eb00cc62>", line 1, in <module>
execute(upload_scripts_data, rps_file)

 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 412, in execute
ran_jobs = jobs.run()

 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/job_queue.py", line 168, in run
self._fill_results(results)

 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/job_queue.py", line 191, in _fill_results
datum = self._comms_queue.get_nowait()

 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 152, in get_nowait
return self.get(False)

 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 135, in get
res = self._recv()

TypeError: ('__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)', <class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError'>, (None, 'Unable to connect to port 22 on  or 54.165.186.168'))

  return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "<ipython-input-19-ed4344124d24>", line 4, in upload_scripts_data
put(path + file_name, "~")
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 677, in host_prompting_wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 345, in put
ftp = SFTP(env.host_string)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/sftp.py", line 33, in __init__
self.ftp = connections[host_string].open_sftp()
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 159, in __getitem__
self.connect(key)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 151, in connect
user, host, port, cache=self, seek_gateway=seek_gateway)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 603, in connect
raise NetworkError(msg, e)
NetworkError: Low level socket error connecting to host 54.165.186.168 on port 22: Unable to connect to port 22 on  or 54.165.186.168 (tried 1 time)
[ubuntu@52.90.34.75] put: /home/rerwin21/amazon_proj/amazon/review_page_scraper.py -> /home/ubuntu/review_page_scraper.py
!!! Parallel execution exception under host u'ubuntu@54.173.57.59':
Process ubuntu@54.173.57.59:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
self.run()
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 242, in inner
submit(task.run(*args, **kwargs))
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 174, in run
return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/decorators.py", line 181, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "<ipython-input-19-ed4344124d24>", line 4, in upload_scripts_data
put(path + file_name, "~")
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 677, in host_prompting_wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 345, in put
ftp = SFTP(env.host_string)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/sftp.py", line 33, in __init__
self.ftp = connections[host_string].open_sftp()
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 159, in __getitem__
self.connect(key)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 151, in connect
user, host, port, cache=self, seek_gateway=seek_gateway)
 File "/home/rerwin21/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 603, in connect
raise NetworkError(msg, e)
NetworkError: Timed out trying to connect to 54.173.57.59 (tried 1 time)
```

I apologize for such a verbose question and output. I've exhausted my knowledge and didn't see anything online that was quite the same as my issue.

**UPDATE:**
A few things to note. I'm using the same security group and AMI that I used with the old key-pair. Next, even more confusing, if I run the `execute(upload_scripts_data, rps_file)` command again and it runs with no errors.

Comment: Check security group for instance with ip `54.173.57.59`. It is allowing incoming tcp connections on port 22? Is it running ssh daemon?

Comment: Thanks @NehalJWani, I'll respond with an update above, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** This does not solve it. The only thing  that solves the issue is to run the parallel command a second time.

Very embarrassing, but I have to post. As I mentioned, I was forced to completely reinstall Ubuntu, and lost my key-pair. What I overlooked was my `ssh_config` file. To fix the problem:

```
sudo gedit
```

Once in gedit, uncomment Port 22:

```
# Port 22
```

to

```
Port 22
```

Save, and now I'm up and running again!